# Existing conjure-up spells or juju bundles that extend the Charmed/Canonical Dist of Kubernetes with storage

Tags: juju, conjure-up

I am looking for an extended spell or charm bundle that includes block storage and ideally object storage as well as Kubernetes storageclasses. I like ceph but I am open to alternatives.

Comment: Have you looked at [storage docs](https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/storage)? Adding strorage (via Ceph) is quite easy and can be done by adding a single relation between ceph-mon and kubernetes-master.

Comment: curious if there is an advantage of doing this over rook/ceph (rook.io). Thanks!